# Angular 2 boilerplate not working

Tags: angular

I have a plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/dAheUrJbJis6LnTe4BXo?p=preview

Super simply, I'm trying to create a basic Angular 2 set-up/bolierplate

Can anyone tell why this isn't working.

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { EventsAppComponent } from "event-app.component";



    @NgModule({
        imports:[
            BrowserModule
        ],

        declarations:[
            EventsAppComponent,

        ],
        providers:[

        ],
        bootstrap:[
            EventsAppComponent
        ]

    })

    export class AppModule{


    }
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? It is of no use to state only that, without explaining the method of failure and any error message you get.

Comment: Sorry, the output should display 'Hello World'

Comment: https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/AwrEzqlyz7OPhK5onfKP?p=preview

• `let world = "world";` should be `world = "world";`

• `template:<h1>Hello {{ world }}</h1>` should be `template:'<h1>Hello {{ world }}</h1>'`

• `event-app.component` should be inside `src` folder.